# Ordering amongst the N requests in 1 io_submit call

Tags: linux

1. If 1 single io_submit calls contains a read and write request to the same (offset, Len), is the read guaranteed to see the value written in write or no?
2. If 1 single io_submit call contains 2 write operations to same (offset, Len), which one will execute first?

In both examples NR = 2 in the io_submit call.

My understanding is that in both examples, the NR sub requests can be processed in any arbitrary order.

Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If 1 single io_submit calls contains a read and write request to the same (offset, Len), is the read guaranteed to see the value written in write or no?

```
No,
```

If 1 single io_submit call contains 2 write operations to same (offset, Len), which one will execute first?

```
The one having lower index in array of pointers to struct iocb.
The requests are submitted to the internal queue of the io_context_t  which are then read for completions. So ordering is of a queue and the algorithm used.
```

Comment: iOS - what do you mean?

Comment: array of pointers to struct iocb , updated the answer